# Converting a character string to numeric

Tags: sas

I am trying to convert a character string to become numeric using input() but I am having trouble fixing the error in my code which says expecting an arithmetic operator and it says I have a syntax error. Originally the column name was Diet which I changed to diet_number and I extracted 1 from Diet 1 which was in the column using substr(Diet, 6, 1);
I dropped Diet so I would only have a column named diet_number with 1 inside of the column. But, it is still a character which is why I am using input. Do I need to name a new column name such as diet_num? What should go inside of the parentheses of input?

```
diet_number=substr(Diet, 6, 1);
drop Diet;
diet_num=input(diet_number);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `input` function requires a second argument specifying the informat to use.
Since your substring is only one character, the informat can be `1.` meaning one digit character

```
diet_num = input(substr(diet,6,1),1.);
```

Also, extracting a single character from a string can be done with the `char` function

```
diet_num = input( char(diet,6), 1. );
```